# NSFetchedResultsController with NSDictionaryResultsType in NSFetchRequest

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have been looking over this issue since a week and haven't got any solution, so I thought to make the question more generalized, may be it will help the users to look into it and give me a solution.

Scenario:

I have an expense tracking iOS Application and I have a view controller called "DashBoardViewController" (table view controller - with FRC) which would basically categorize my expenses/incomes for a given week, a month, or year and display it as the section header title for example : (Oct 1- Oct 7, 2012) and it shows expenses/incomes ROWS and related stuff according to that particular week or month or year.

My Question:

What I want to accomplish is :

Show Distinct Results based on "Category" attribute of "Money" entity and calculate "Sum" based on the attribute.

But, my view controller called "dashboard view controller" is filled with NSFetchedResultsController with section name key path as "type" that can be an expense or an income. In order to get Distinct results, I shall use Result type as NSDictionaryResultsType in my fetch request which will give me unique results but FRC fails, it doesn't work with that. So, how will I get my section names then? I have posted the code below.

EDIT - BASED ON MARTIN'S SUGGESTION

```m
   - (void)userDidSelectStartDate:(NSDate *)startDate andEndDate:(NSDate *)endDate
{
    AppDelegate * applicationDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext * context = [applicationDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Money" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSPredicate *predicateDate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", startDate, endDate];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicateDate];


    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.

    typeSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"type" ascending:YES];

    dateSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];

    if(self.choiceSegmentedControl.selectedIndex == 0)
    {
        choiceSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"cat" ascending:NO];
    }

    if(self.choiceSegmentedControl.selectedIndex == 1)
    {
        choiceSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"vendor" ascending:NO];
    }

    if(self.choiceSegmentedControl.selectedIndex == 2)
    {        
        choiceSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"paidBy" ascending:NO];
    }

    NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:typeSortDescriptor, dateSortDescriptor,choiceSortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:descriptors];
    [fetchRequest setIncludesSubentities:YES];

    NSError * anyError = nil;

    NSArray *propertiesToFetch = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                  [entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"cat"],
                                  nil];

    [fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:propertiesToFetch];

    NSArray * objects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&anyError];

    for (NSDictionary *d in objects)
    {
        NSLog(@"NSDictionary = %@", d);
    }

    NSSet *uniqueSet = [NSSet setWithArray:[objects valueForKey:@"cat"]];

    uniqueArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[uniqueSet allObjects]];

    self.categoryArray = uniqueArray;

    if(_fetchedResultsController)
    {
        [_fetchedResultsController release]; _fetchedResultsController = nil;

    }

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:@"type" cacheName:nil];

    //self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self; in order to stop "change tracking"

    if(![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&anyError])
    {
        NSLog(@"error fetching:%@", anyError);
    }

    [fetchRequest release];

    //Finally you tell the tableView to reload it's data, it will then ask your NEW FRC for the new data
    [self.dashBoardTblView reloadData];

    self.startDate = startDate;
    self.endDate = endDate;


}
```

With this code, SECTION NAME KEY PATH is not working and it's complaining that the object will be placed in unnamed section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fetched results controller does not support change tracking (i.e. the FRC delegate is set) in combination with a fetch request with `NSDictionaryResultType`.

The reason is documented with the `setIncludesPendingChanges:` function:

> **Special Considerations**
>
> A value of YES is not supported in conjunction
>   with the result type NSDictionaryResultType, including calculation of
>   aggregate results (such as max and min). For dictionaries, the array
>   returned from the fetch reflects the current state in the persistent
>   store, and does not take into account any pending changes, insertions,
>   or deletions in the context.

Change tracking of the FRC implies `includesPendingChanges = YES` for the fetch request, and that does not work with `NSDictionaryResultType`.

One workaround could be to use a FRC *without change tracking*, so you do not set the FRC delegate. But that means that to update your table view, you have to

- save the managed object context, and
- call `performFetch` on the FRC and `reloadData` on the table view.

Another workaround could be to use the FRC to fetch all sections and rows without the sum aggregation, and use the results to compute new table rows with the aggregation in memory (e.g. in `controllerDidChangeContent`).

**UPDATE:** (From the discussion) Another important point is that if you use a fetch request with `NSDictionaryResultType`, then the `sectionNameKeyPath` of the fetched results controller must be included in the `propertiesToFetch` of the fetch request.

Comment: So, in the above method, what do you think I should do in order to make the section name exist and also fetch distinct results with aggregation.

Comment: The second approach you mentioned "to use FRC to fetch all sections and rows" but it won't give me distinct rows for my categories.

Comment: @AngadManchanda: Why don't you try the first approach, that is perhaps easier to implement.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Facing problem in getting section now. I just added the code for that.

Comment: since the frc delegate is nil, the number of sections returned is always 1 now for the table view. How would I manage that? I have added code for table view data source and delegate methods as well.

Comment: @AngadManchanda: "since the frc delegate is nil, the number of sections returned is always 1 now for the table view" - this makes no sense.

Comment: Can we continue the discussion in the chat , http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19357/discussion-between-martin-r-and-angad-manchanda