# NSFetchResultsController with distinct values

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

How does one use NSFetchResultsController for distinct values?

e.g. Core-Data entity Person with 2 attributes name, age.

Searching in the NSFetchResultsController for unique ages, returning the name and age for each unique age?

Comment: Do you need the fetched results controller for displaying a table view? What should be displayed if you have different names with the same age?

Comment: I have 5 viewcontrollers that all need data from core data, but with different criteria. One needs only 2 properties, e.g. all unique ages, return the age and name. One needs all entries sorted by name, another needs all unique values for a specific attribute. The last 2 hold values in an exact ordering, by fetching a deserialized managed object id. They are all tableviews except for one which has a scrollview.

Comment: But if there is more than 1 name for a unique age, which one do you want to display?

Comment: Person is a bad example. A better example is a database of tv show episodes. An episode has a title, a series title, studio, runtime. I would like to be able to find all the unique series titles, returning these and the studio linked to that found unique series title. So there could be multiple unique series names with the same studio name displayed. I think I have to do this manually.

Comment: So you want to find all unique combinations of title/studio or name/age?

Comment: For every unique title, return the title and the studio for the title.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26342/discussion-between-martin-r-and-helium3)

Comment: If my answer does not yet help, it would be good if you show some typical data and the expected output.

Comment: Hi. I tried what you suggested, although I added two more properties that I needed. It returned a distinct set across all properties and I got more results than I need. I would like to use one distinct value, but returning 3 more properties within that same object which holds the distinct value, rather than pulling out the entire managed object.

Comment: I am afraid that we are moving in circles. - Suppose you have three objects "age=30, name=John", "age=30, name=David", "age=40, name=Henry". Fetching unique distinct values of "age" gives ("30", "40"). But which name should be displayed for "age=30"?

Comment: I think its better to drop the person example. For any set of data, how would one extract the distinct values for a property, returning extra properties for the row containing the distinct value, but not including these extra properties in the distinct value search.

Comment: Continued in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26342/discussion-between-martin-r-and-helium3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your last comment I assume that you want to fetch all *unique combinations* of age and name (or series title and studio). This can be done with the following fetch request:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"name", @"age"]];
[fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

This gives an array of dictionaries, containing all unique age/name combinations.

There is one problem however. If you use this fetch request with a fetched results controller, you loose the ability of automatic change tracking (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13550383/1187415 for an explanation). I don't think there is a method to have both: automatic change tracking *and* a fetch request returning distinct results.